# Can I use 'sep=' line with standart CSV module

Tags: python, csv

I have some csv files that have `sep=,` as the first line.

for example

```
sep=,
Col 1,Col 2,
11.01.2017 21:56,Some data
....
```

And I need to read it and write it with `csv` module Now it looks like:

```
with open("file.csv", 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.readline()
    fp = csv.DictReader(file, dialect='excel', delimiter=',')
```

And the same when writing:

```
with open("file.csv", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.writeline()
    fp = csv.DictWriter(file, dialect='excel', delimiter=',')
```

But I wonder if there is any more standart way in csv module to support such csv format?

Answer (score 1):

When you call file.readline() you could strip 'sep=' from the value, and then assign it to a variable. Then, use that variable as delimiter:

```
csv_sep = file.readline()[4:]
fp = csv.DictReader(file, dialect='excel', delimiter=csv_sep)
```

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but  me question is if there is any special format for standart `csv` mofrule to handle that. Like use `dialect='excel_with_sep_line'` insted of `dialect='excel'`